# Running docker images on Windows - docker-entrypoint.sh sourcing /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker

I am trying to run a docker image with a database for my API

`docker run -p 1232:1232 -t image/database`

but this does not work. The error I am getting is:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/Z1init.sql
CREATE ROLE
CREATE DATABASE
GRANT

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: sourcing /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/Z2restoredb.sh
: invalid optionnt-initdb.d/Z2restoredb.sh: line 2: set: -
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
```

I tried several things and nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to figure out what was the problem! 
It was the `Windows` end-of-line characters!

There were some files which did not have the proper end-of-line characters in my `sh` script, so all I had to do was to change the line separator from CRLF (Windows `\r\n`) to LF (Unix `\n`)

[image]